# Coloring Cells in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I am able to import data from an Excel file with Pandas by using:

```
xl = read_excel('path_to_file.xls', 'Sheet1', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])
```

Now that I have all the data in `xl` as a `DataFrame`, I would like to colour  some cells in that data based on conditions defined in another function before exporting the same data (with colour coding) to an Excel file.

How can I color specific cells in a Pandas `DataFrame`?

Comment: Which library should I be using for it then?

Comment: [xlwt](http://www.python-excel.org) or [xlutils](http://pythonhosted.org/xlutils/index.html). May be also http://xlwings.org (free) or https://datanitro.com (paid) for controlling excel directly. Pandas is not designed to manipulate excel files, it just reads from them and makes easy to make calculations.

Comment: openpyxl is well maintained and has seen many recent update

Comment: Are you looking to generate hexadecimal colors based on the values pulled from the spreadsheet, or **actually color the cells in the Excel Workbook**?  Sorry, I wasn't clear on that point from your question.

Comment: I would like to colour the cells in the Excel Workbook.

Comment: You can use the `xlsxwriter` engine from Pandas to apply a conditional format to data in an Excel worksheet. See this answer to [Easiest way to create a color gradient on excel using python/pandas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265403/easiest-way-to-create-a-color-gradient-on-excel-using-python-pandas/26268303#26268303). That may be close to what you want to do.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Pandas has a relatively new `Styler` feature where you can apply conditional formatting type manipulations to dataframes.
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html

You can use some of their built-in functions like `background_gradient` or `bar` to replicate excel-like features like conditional formatting and data bars. You can also format cells to display percentages, floats, ints, etc. without changing the original dataframe.

Here's an example of the type of chart you can make using `Styler` (this is a nonsense chart but just meant to demonstrate features):

[image]

To harness the full functionality of `Styler` you should get comfortable with the `Styler.apply()` and `Styler.applymap()` APIs. These allow you to create custom functions and apply them to the table's columns, rows or elements. For example, if I wanted to color a +ive cell green and a -ive cell red, I'd create a function

```
def _color_red_or_green(val):
    color = 'red' if val < 0 else 'green'
    return 'color: %s' % color
```

and call it on my `Styler` object, i.e., `df.style.applymap(_color_red_or_green)`.

With respect to exporting back to Excel, as far as I'm aware this is not supported in `Styler` yet so I'd probably go the xlsxwriter route if you NEED Excel for some reason. However, in my experience this is a great pure Python alternative, for example along with matplotlib charts and in emails/reports.

Comment: Exporting Styler objects back to Excel is supported as of Pandas 0.20.0 --https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_excel.html

Comment: @wkzhu when I attempt to run your code I get "<pandas.core.style.Styler at 0x259e2be0> instead of the table displaying, any ideas?

Comment: @trock2000 https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Building-styles have you tried with this example? Are you running on Jupyter notebook?

Comment: @wkzhu as you inferred, the issue was I was running this in Spyder - have it working in Jupyter now, thx

Answer (score 13):

The most simple way is to use applymap and lambda if you only want to highlight certain values:

```
df.style.applymap(lambda x: "background-color: red" if x>0 else "background-color: white")
```

Comment: is there a library of color data available for discrete and continuous mappings for python, similar to [Wolfram's ColorData](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorData.html)?

Comment: @alancalvitti I am not sure, but you can pass hex values in as options.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few ideas  about styling the cells on the [Pandas website](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html).
However it ist mentioned: *This is a new feature and still under development. We'll be adding features and possibly making breaking changes in future releases*

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
with pandas.io.excel.ExcelWriter(path=Path, engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
   sheet = writer.book.worksheets()[0]
   sheet.write(x, y, value, format) #format is what determines the color etc.
```

More info here: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/format.html