# Coloring cells in pandas according to their relative value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to color the cells of a (python) pandas dataframe according to wether their value is in the top 5%, top 10%, ..., last 10%, last 5% of the data in this column.

According to this post [Coloring Cells in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075699/coloring-cells-in-pandas), one can define a function and then apply it to the dataframe.

If you want to color cell if they are in a fixed range, this works fine. 
But if you want to color only the first 5%, you need to have all the information about the column. Hence you cannot apply a function that only evaluates every single cell.

Hence my question: 
Is there a smart way to color the top 5%, 10%,... of a dataframe in each column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100).reshape(20,-1))

def colorme(x):
    c = x.rank(pct=True)
    c = np.select([c<=.05,c<=.10,c>=.95,c>=.90],['red','orange','yellow','green'])
    return [f'background-color: {i}' for i in c]

df.style.apply(colorme)
```

[image]

Comment: Oops, I think I meant to make 'green' greater than .95 and yellow greater than .90.  Anyway, I think you can use this method.