# Color value of key 'CountMatch result' in dict obj

Tags: python, pandas

```
 **testdict** =  {'Dict_1': {'Start Time': '06-10-2020 13:08:58', 'Test Type': 'ERP_To_DBO','CountMatch Result': 'Failed', 'End Time': '06-10-2020 13:09:16'},

'Dict_2': {'Start Time': '06-10-2020 13:09:21', 'Test Type': 'ERP_To_DBO','CountMatch Result': 'Failed', 'End Time': '06-10-2020 13:11:53'}, 

'Dict_2': {'Start Time': '06-10-2020 13:11:59', 'Test Type': 'ERP_To_DBO', 'CountMatch Result': 'Failed', 'End Time': '06-10-2020 13:13:19'}}
```

I want to highlight value 'failed' with red and 'Passed' with green.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=testdict)

def color_negative_red(val):
   color = 'red' if val == 'Failed' else 'black'
     return 'color: %s' % color

 df = df.style.apply(color_mapper)
 df.transpose().to_html(filename)
```

I have tried many things listed in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html but didn't got any success.

once the style has applied i have to transpose the entire DF and render a DataFrame as an HTML table.

Answer (score 1):

Try operating on the entire column at a time inside your function:

```
def color_mapper(values):
    mapping = {'Failed': 'red', 'Passed': 'green'}
    return [
        'background-color: {}'.format(mapping.get(v, 'black') for v in values]

df.style.apply(color_mapper)
```

Comment: Unfortunately above code isn't working.. - https://imgur.com/ZxtlpS9

Comment: @Techie please remember to add .render() like you did in your question

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't running because you should use `applymap()` when styling and also because return is inside a condition, so when value enter in one of the two first conditionals, the function will never return. Now, when you are using `applymap()` you are applying a function to each value of your dataframe, so you can era the `for key, value in value():`. Try change code like this:

```
def color_failed_red(value): 
    if value =='Failed':
      color = 'red'
    elif value == 'Passed':
      color = 'green'
    else:
      color = 'black'
    return 'color: %s' % color
df.style.applymap(color_failed_red).render()
df.to_html('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\testresult.html')
```

You can see the explanation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html). And you also should know that Pandas styler only works in the Jupyter notebook for now, according to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58116600/pandas-styler-not-printing-dataframe-to-spyders-console-as-expected/58118375#58118375), so when yo do:

```
print(df.style.applymap(color_failed_red))
>>><pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x7f91368b4b80>
```

If anything, you'll get the expected result if you use `applymap()` and edit the code as I showed you before. But, I tried another solution, more exemplifying script, so you can see how the color changed. Nonetheless, I didn't get the perfect result. But in case you  maybe prefer this solution and want to work in it, this is what I've been trying :

```
def color_failed_red(x):
  color=''
  if x =='Failed':
    color = '\033[91m'  #red
  elif x == 'Passed':
    color = '\033[92m'  #green
  else:
    color=''
  return color+x
df1=df.applymap(color_failed_red)
print(df1)
```

Output:

[image: approach to solution]
I got this way of print colored from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-in-terminal-in-python).

Comment: this throwing error 'return color+x' Exception has occurred: TypeError
can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: Tha'ts weird, since all the values in df are strings. I've test it in cmd, online compiler, spyder and jupyter, and I got no errors. Where are you running the script?

Comment: Still weird, can you check if `'\033[91m'` is string type?  And can you try something like `return color+str(x)`?