# Conditional Formatting Within a Pandas DataFrame in Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization

I have an arbitrary dataframe, something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'col_3':[100,-100, 50, -50,]})
df
```

[image: Sample picture of dataframe]

is there a way to change the formatting for each item in such a way that larger values within a column are one color and smaller values are another? Preferably the implementation would be:

- something brief
- able to be applied to most simple dataframes
- robust enough to handle different datatypes

---

as an example, Excel has conditional formatting which looks like this:

[image: excel conditional formatting]

It doesn't do anything meaningful with strings or chars, but otherwise behaves nicely

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075699/coloring-cells-in-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many amazing things, you can do it with `seaborn`

this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'col_3':[100,-100, 50, -50,]})

import seaborn as sns
cm = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)
s = df.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm)
s
```

makes this:

[image: formatted table]