# How to categorize strings in pandas and color them with seaborn by category?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, seaborn, pandas-styles

I'm working on my problem, so I created minimal reproducible example, maybe you can help me. I want to categories strings and color them in excel sheet by categories. I have multiindex and I want to color only one column ('new') from items.

This is code...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[2020], [1, 2, 3, 4]],
                                   names=['year', 'q'])
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Items1', 'Items2', 'Items3'], ['new', 'old']],
                                     names=['Items', 'type'])

data = np.random.seed(123)
data = list(np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), (4,6)))

Ldata = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)
Ldata
```

I got table something like this...

[image]

I want to categorize strings, maybe I can do it with lists like this

```
category1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
category2 = ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
category3 = ['l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p']
category4 = ['q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'w']
category5 = ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

When I got letters from category one, I want to color it with red (it can be other color), and gradually to go to middle (category3), and from there some other color like green to gradually go category5 (where it will have stronger color).

[image]

So far I used a seaborn to color background of cell, before I export it to excel. Any idea how do I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think looking for solutions to this is going to heavily depend on how you are viewing your `DataFrame`. It looks like you are using jupyter, so I think this answer might fit your needs: [Coloring Cells in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075699/coloring-cells-in-pandas)

I would look to this part of the answer, and make the logic of this function more complex (to meet your `category1, category2...` needs):

```
def _color_red_or_green(val):
    color = 'red' if val < 0 else 'green'
    return 'color: %s' % color
```

To do that, I would also use two separate `dict`, one that maps between letters and the group, and another that maps between the groups and the colors. So something like:

```
def _color_mapper(val):
    groups = {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'f': 2, 'h':2}
    colors = {1: 'red', 2: '#f5e042', 3: (245, 224, 66)} 
    return colors[groups[val]]
```

Comment: I like this solution, can you apply it on code that I have provided? I'm getting this `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'style'`