# How would I find the quarterly averages of these monthly figures?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My dataset is similar to the below:

```
data = [['Jane', 10,10.5,11,45,66,21,88,99,77,41,22], ['John',11,22,55,34,44,22,44,55,88,56,47],['Tom',23,32,43,12,11,44,77,85,99,45,63]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', '09-Aug-21', 'Aug-21', '02-Sep-21', 'Sep-21', '18-Oct-21', 'Oct-21', '02-Nov-21','Nov-21','14-Dec-21', 'Dec-21', '15-Jan-22'])
df
```

[image]

How can I add columns to this which show the quarterly figure, which is an average of the preceding three months? Eg, suppose we started at adding a column after 'Dec-21' called Q4 2021 which took the average of the columns called 'Oct-21', 'Nov-21' and 'Dec-21'.

Will I need to create a function which takes the preceding three values and returns an average, and then concatenate this to my dataframe? It does not have to be directly after each period, eg I am also happy to add all of the Quarterly averages right at the end.

Comment: Did you forget to add the "day" portion of some of the columns or is that just how the data is structured?

Comment: That is how it is, the columns without the days are the monthly figures for that respective month, interpolated by taking the time weighted average between the preceding and proceeding dates.

Comment: So would you be looking to get a quarter average of only those columns without a day date?

Comment: Yes that is spot on.

Comment: @work_python, posted a solution. does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from datetime import datetime

def get_quarter_name(timestamp):
    """Convert '2021-12-01' to 'Q4-2021'
    """
    return f"Q{timestamp.quarter}-{timestamp.year}"

# your data
data = [['Jane', 10,10.5,11,45,66,21,88,99,77,41,22], ['John',11,22,55,34,44,22,44,55,88,56,47],['Tom',23,32,43,12,11,44,77,85,99,45,63]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', '09-Aug-21', 'Aug-21', '02-Sep-21', 'Sep-21', '18-Oct-21', 'Oct-21', '02-Nov-21','Nov-21','14-Dec-21', 'Dec-21', '15-Jan-22'])

# filter only relevant columns, which start with an alphabetical character
cols = [col for col in df.columns if not col[0].isdigit()]

# extract only relevant columns and transpose
df_T = df[cols].set_index("Name").T

# convert index values to dates
df_T.index = pd.Index([pd.Timestamp(datetime.strptime(d,'%b-%y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) for d in df_T.index])

# resample by Quarters and transpose again to original format
df_quarter = df_T.resample("Q").mean().T

# rename columns to quarter-like descriptions
df_quarter.columns = [get_quarter_name(col) for col in df_quarter.columns]
```

`df_quarter` is your final answer which you can merge back to original `df`

Output:

```
      Q3-2021    Q4-2021
Name                    
Jane    27.75  53.666667
John    28.00  44.333333
Tom     22.00  58.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

```
# Define your quarters month
q1=['Aug','Sep']
q2=['Oct','Nov']
q3=['Dec','Jan']


df['q1']=df[df.columns[(df.columns.str.contains(rf'|'.join(q1)) )]].mean(axis=1)
df['q2']=df[df.columns[(df.columns.str.contains(rf'|'.join(q2)) )]].mean(axis=1)
df['q3']=df[df.columns[(df.columns.str.contains(rf'|'.join(q3)) )]].mean(axis=1)
df
```

```
    Name    09-Aug-21   Aug-21  02-Sep-21   Sep-21  18-Oct-21   Oct-21  02-Nov-21   Nov-21  14-Dec-21   Dec-21  15-Jan-22       q1     q2          q3
0   Jane           10     10.5         11       45         66       21         88       99         77       41         22   19.125  68.50   46.666667
1   John           11     22.0         55       34         44       22         44       55         88       56         47   30.500  41.25   63.666667
2   Tom            23     32.0         43       12         11       44         77       85         99       45         63   27.500  54.25   69.000000
```

Comment: Thanks but I have a few questions. I require the average for every quarter every year. This only adds three columns? Also, what about Q4?

Comment: @work_python, you had 6 months in the sample data, and I divide it up into three. you change q1, q2, q3 and your result will be according to it.  Now, can you elaborate what you meant by every year? it helps if you share the representative data along with the expected out in a table.

Answer (score 1):

This is kinda messy, but it SHOULD allow you to dynamically generate a column for each quarter (does not have the quarter year you could add that logic if you want).

```
data = [['Jane', 10,10.5,11,45,66,21,88,99,77,41,22], ['John',11,22,55,34,44,22,44,55,88,56,47],['Tom',23,32,43,12,11,44,77,85,99,45,63]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', '09-Aug-21', 'Aug-21', '02-Sep-21', 'Sep-21', '18-Oct-21', 'Oct-21', '02-Nov-21','Nov-21','14-Dec-21', 'Dec-21', '15-Jan-22'])
columns_to_use = [column for column in df.columns if column[0].isalpha()]
df = df[columns_to_use]
df = df.melt(id_vars = 'Name')
df['variable'] = '01-' + df['variable']
df['variable'] = pd.to_datetime(df['variable'],infer_datetime_format=True)
df['Quarter'] = df['variable'].dt.quarter
df['Quarter_Avg'] = df.groupby(['Name', 'Quarter'])['value'].transform('mean')

df1 = df.groupby(['Name', 'Quarter'])['Quarter_Avg'].agg('mean').reset_index()
df1['Quarter'] = 'Quarter ' + df1['Quarter'].astype(str)
df1 = df1.pivot_table(index = 'Name', columns = 'Quarter', values = 'Quarter_Avg').reset_index()

df['variable'] = df['variable'].astype(str)
df['variable'] = df['variable'].apply(lambda x : '-'.join(x.split('-')[0:2]))
df = df.pivot_table(index = 'Name', columns = 'variable', values = 'value').reset_index()

df_final = df.merge(df1, on = 'Name')
df_final
```

Answer (score 1):

A fair amount of steps but it gives you the expected result

```py
from datetime import datetime

data = [['Jane', 10,10.5,11,45,66,21,88,99,77,41,22,22], ['John',11,22,55,34,44,22,44,55,88,56,47,47],['Tom',23,32,43,12,11,44,77,85,99,45,63,63]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', '09-Aug-21', 'Aug-21', '02-Sep-21', 'Sep-21', '18-Oct-21', 'Oct-21', '02-Nov-21','Nov-21','14-Dec-21', 'Dec-21', '15-Jan-22', 'Jan-22'])

# Melt the data frame by date
meltedDF = df.melt(id_vars=["Name"], var_name=["Date"])

# Remove the dates that don't match the "Month-year" format
meltedDF = meltedDF[pd.to_datetime(meltedDF.Date, format='%b-%y', errors='coerce').notna()].reset_index(drop=True)

# Convert those dates to datetime objects
meltedDF["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(meltedDF.Date, format='%b-%y')

# Find the quarter that those dates fall into and add the year string to the that quarter
meltedDF["Quarter"] = "Q" + meltedDF.Date.dt.quarter.astype(str) + " " + meltedDF.Date.dt.year.astype(str)

# Group by the quarter and the person's name then get the mean of their values
meltedDF = meltedDF.groupby(["Quarter", "Name"], as_index=False).mean().round(1)

# Pivot the table's Quarter values to be column names
meltedDF = pd.pivot_table(meltedDF, index=['Name'], values=['value'], columns="Quarter")

# Combine the names and the Quarter total values
meltedDF = pd.concat([meltedDF.reset_index()["Name"], meltedDF.reset_index()["value"]], axis=1)

# Merge these values back into the original Dataframe
df = df.merge(meltedDF, left_on='Name', right_on='Name')
```

Output:

```
    Name    09-Aug-21   Aug-21  02-Sep-21   Sep-21  18-Oct-21   Oct-21  02-Nov-21   Nov-21  14-Dec-21   Dec-21  15-Jan-22   Jan-22  Q1 2022 Q3 2021 Q4 2021
0   Jane    10  10.5    11  45  66  21  88  99  77  41  22  22  22.0    27.8    53.7
1   John    11  22.0    55  34  44  22  44  55  88  56  47  47  47.0    28.0    44.3
2   Tom     23  32.0    43  12  11  44  77  85  99  45  63  63  63.0    22.0    58.0
```