# How to visualize spatial agronomical data in Python?

Tags: python, grid, data-visualization, heatmap

I am quite new to python and I am looking for a way to have a visual representation of my field values. Like a grid heatmap.

I have an excel file (that I import with pd.read_excel) that looks like this:

#  X   Y    Score

1          1   1      44

2          2   1      37

3          3   1      0

4          3   2      100

And so on.

[Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObM9n.png)

I know there is a way to use 2d numpy array into a grid but have not found how to do it with my excel file.

I want something that will look like this at the end

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAj8u.png)

Can someone help me please?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something like this (you can change the colormap if you like):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
nrows = 2
ncols = 2

# Main Plot
score = np.array(df["Score"]).reshape(nrows,ncols)
plt.matshow(score,cmap=plt.cm.jet)

# Grid Labels
row_labels = range(1,nrows+1)
col_labels = range(1,ncols+1)
plt.xticks(range(ncols), col_labels)
plt.yticks(range(nrows), row_labels)

# Write Score
for i in range(ncols):
    for j in range(nrows):
        print(score[i,j])
        plt.text(i, j, score[i,j], va='center', ha='center',color='white',size='20',weight='bold')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) Is there a way to use a gradual color for the score, for example, low score red, then up to medium turns orange and to high green? Thank you in advance

Comment: You can change the colormap in the line `plt.matshow(score,cmap=plt.cm.jet)`
You can checkout more about colomaps here: https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html

Answer (score 0):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265403/easiest-way-to-create-a-color-gradient-on-excel-using-python-pandas). It uses the Excel's conditional formatting feature using Xlsx Writer. See [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html) as well.