# Python Excel styling using Pandas Library

Tags: python, pandas, colors

I am coding a school project rn, where I have to analyse stocks and predict them. So now my problem is the code is finished, but I want to add colours in my Excel file.

I am using the following libraries:

- requests
- bs4
- pandas
- datetime

So I looked up the whole Internet and found nothing helpful. This is my code where the Excel file is written:

```
def write_xlsx():
    help = []
    for i in range(len(new_price)):
        list = []
        list.append(new_price[i])
        list.append(price_dif[i])
        list.append(high[i])
        list.append(low[i])
        list.append(keepsell[i])
        help.append(list)
    list = [datetime.now(), None, None, None, None]
    help.append(list)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(help, index=[get_names()], columns=['Price (€)', 'Difference (€)', 'High (€)', 'Low (€)', 'Prediction'])
    try:
        df1.to_excel("Stock.xlsx", sheet_name='Stonks')
    except:
        print("Please close the Exel Document within 15 seconds!")
        time.sleep(15)
        df1.to_excel("Stock.xlsx", sheet_name='Stonks')
```

I want to color my Price Differences or the High|Low column. Can you please help me how to color the Excel file.

If you need more code let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See these posts in the Stack Overflow:

Reference-1: [Coloring Cells in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075699/coloring-cells-in-pandas)

Reference-2: [Easiest way to create a color gradient on excel using python/pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265403/easiest-way-to-create-a-color-gradient-on-excel-using-python-pandas/26268303#26268303)